# Is there any lite Ubuntu version for an old PC?

Tags: compatibility

I'm currently stuck with an old PC with amd-core processor and 2GB RAM. Windows isn't doing well so I've switched to Linux and want to know if there is any lite version of Ubuntu available for basic use.

Answer (score 3):

You have [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

[image]

And [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

[image]

And [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

[image]

I would go for mate, it looks *very* nice **=D**

Comment: +1 Good choices for low resource computers, and nice pics of desktops

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to stick within the Ubuntu family of linux distros, then [LUBUNTU](http://lubuntu.net/) comes to mind first. It's based on Ubuntu, with LXDE as the DE. It runs fairly well, with enough features to make the basic user happy.

Another option is to go with [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), which uses the MATE desktop environment. It may require a bit more resources from your computer, but it may give you a better/different experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Ubuntu Mate is what you are looking for:

[Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

Alternatively;

[Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)